# Eclipse not able to resolve Maven dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have been working on a Java Maven project and my way of using it in Eclipse was to build it on command line and then import in Eclipse. The problem that I was facing is even though the project built successfully, eclipse was not able to resolve dependencies correctly.

This problem would usually go by cleaning, Maven updating and deleting and importing. However, this time it did not get resolved by following these steps. I tried a lot of already existing answers but nothing worked for me. However, I observed that the classpath is not getting created correctly:

[image: Java Build Path]

I'm seeing that one of the dependency jars is marked as missing

I tried to create the Eclipse .classpath file using:

```
mvn eclipse:clean
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

But `mvn eclipse:eclipse` fails with the following message:

> Failed to execute goal on project consultation: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project
>   company.compliance:consultation:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find
>   company.compliance:commons:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in
>   http://maven.ia55.net/company was cached in the local repository,
>   resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
>   company-mvn-repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

I read in some of the answers that this can also happen if m2e is not configured properly (it should be pointing to the commandline maven and not embedded maven). When I checked I saw that I don't even have m2e so in installed it. I don't know how to configure it to point to my Maven.

However, I doubt that this problem is because of the plugin not working otherwise I would not have been able to work in Eclipse peacefully till now.

So my other question is, isn't the success of `mvn clean package` enough to warrant that eclipse should not have any compilation errors regarding dependencies or does scope of dependency also plays a role and that I should work on getting the jar in the repo.

Is there any other possible issue that I am missing?

Comment: Does your company host its own Maven Nexus repository? Or did you delete your .m2 cache recently?

Comment: Are you able to build using command?

Comment: @Blundell i deleted it recently

Comment: That's your problem, it's looking for a dependency `company.compliance:consultation:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT` and can't find it. You deleted it

Comment: @Blundell but would n't it get the jar from the nexus repository? even if i deleted it from my local

Comment: @Sambit yes i am using command line

Comment: You might have deleted the config that included the address of your company's maven repo. I remember mine was located in the .m2 folder, but that location is configurable.

Comment: @second this project has huge dependencies. If that were the case, then out of so many why would only this be marked as missing.. Let me confirm though.

Comment: You can check under `Preferences` -> `Maven` -> `User Settings`. Check that either the global or user settings contain the address for your companies repo. But when running from commandline the location of your configuration might be different.

Comment: @second Checked. user settings is blank and global settings contains settings.xml in a shared location and it contains the company url.

Comment: In that case you might want to check your local `.m2` folder. Navigate to the location where your companies jar is supposed to be. If its not there, but a  folder exists with some other flles, delete it and run maven update again. Also check your companies repo that the dependency is actually there and downloadable via the nexus website.

Comment: @second it's looking for snapshot jar whereas in my companies repo has a different version available. the version mentioned in the pom.xml is ${compliance.version} which is supposed to get replaced i think to correct version however it is getting replaced to the snapshot jar

Comment: And the scope is provided so i guess because of that it is getting build without any compilation errors.

Comment: @second <properties>
        <compliance.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</compliance.version>.....</properties> is mentioned in pom. Because of which it is defaulting to this jar i guess.. don't know how and when or even if the correct dependency version is supposed to be picked or repo SHOULD contain the snapshot jar which it is not having currently(checked)

Comment: *"resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of company-mvn-repository has elapsed or updates are forced"* can you force it to update? `mvn clean install -U`

Comment: If the version you're trying to retrieve is not in the nexus, then you are out of luck. Maybe there was a release and your snapshot version is now outdated. Ask your colleagues about it.

Comment: @Blundell Forcing the update also did n't help.. it's still displaying the same error message.

Comment: Perhaps the companies nexus no longer has a copy of that snapshot jar? Do you have a copy anywhere, recyclebin etc?

Comment: @Blundell Yes. There is no snapshot jar available in the repo. I don't have a copy but i'll hardcode it to that version for now(maybe that will work) and check with my teammates about why the snapshot is not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved. Earlier i was only importing the project that i wanted to work on. After importing all the projects in the directory which contained the pom, eclipse resolved the dependencies. Have no clue how this worked but it did.